# Is solvent fitted 2” pvc safe for use with drinking water?

Tags: plumbing, water, pvc, cpvc, water-purification

I have a 500 gal outdoor drinking water storage barrel, that I want to attach a hydrant to (the hand operated type)

Yes I know the water will need to be disinfected after pulling it from the barrel. I have a Berkey filter and a big stove for this.

Bear in mind that NO HOT WATER WILL TOUCH THE PIPE, and I will shield the pipe from the sun.

My question is, if I run 2 in pvc fittings and pipe to the hydrant, using solvent glue, will any chemicals leach into the water?

Also I have seen 2” pipe that is marked drain/waste/vent only. But I understand this is only because they don’t want it hitting hot water. If only cold water touches the pipe is it safe to drink from?

Is cpvc a better choice? Can I find it in 2in fittings?

If folks answering can provide references, that’d be even “awesomer” :-)

Comment: Duplicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31364/is-pvc-schedule-40-pipe-safe-to-use-in-a-potable-water-supply

Answer (score 1):

PVC is safe to use for drinking water. In fact it is getting tough to find non plastic means for water delivery at a reasonable cost. PVC & CPVC have been used for many decades larger sizes that city water systems use have o ring or rubber seals this allows the pipe some flex but I don't think rubber starts being used until 4" . is it safe yes, follow the instructions so it can cure. Since it is only cold water you don't need cpvc that was designed for hot water. You would never use ABS drain wast only on a supply and that may be what is causing the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t trust it. Sure it might work but if I come over and you offer me a drink from that I would gladly say no. Your right that only cold water/drain water is ok to run for pvc. But PVC is made of chemicals inside the pipe. Giving it that “plastic taste” when you drink it. I’d also be afraid of the glue and primer chemicals too. Basically it will work if you use slip on PVC fittings and no glue/primer. It would still work with glue and primer but I’d be afraid of the chemicals in the glue and primer. At your own risk type of thing

Comment: Pvc has been used for decades for water supplies, cpvc for hot water because PVC can fail with hot water that's why you don't see large sizes of cpvc larger hot water needs usually go copper for drinking water. I believe you may be thinking of abs that is for drains. PVC plastics can be found in almost 100 % of drinking water supplies, ever open up your faucet most modern faucets have plastic parts.

Comment: Copper is also a chemical, by the way. In fact, water is a chemical. Are your afraid of water as well?